# Naviagation Drawer Stuck with Fragments Injection

Tags: android

I am trying to add to the navigation drawer using fragments as follows using the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected But the compiler is giving me a incomparable type I do not no how I am new to Andriod I used the NaviagationDrwaer Template app to give me heads start.

I am hopeing someone can point me in the right direction with this been driving me nuts. Also any ideas with this apporach how one would handle icons in the menu ?.

```
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new  HomeFragment();  --- This line is where the error comes
            break;

    }        

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();

}
```

My HomeFragment Class Conists Of

```
public class HomeFragment extends  Fragment  {
    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

And my home_layout file as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.davidbuckley.cautioapp.home">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your fragments is probably a 'support' Fragment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html

While the other is probably a native Fragment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: I understand that but how do i reference that in the switch statment I only added that home fragment do the default project can you provide an example plz all the fragments in code extends fragment weird

Comment: Change the import in the class containing `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` to match the class type you're extending in `HomeFragment`.

Comment: That does not solve it brings more error than worth im sure a simpliar solution

Comment: Link me gists containing the entire source for each of those two files.

Comment: If you create a standard navigationdrawer template project then just add a fragment called home you will get what im wanting to do

Comment: Then your `HomeFragment` is extending from the wrong Fragment try swapping that instead to match the Fragment type in `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected`